# Trying to implement Observer Patterns and got Segmentation Fault (pls help) c++

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, gdb, observer-pattern

I'm trying to learn c++ so, I try to implement the observer patterns from the book Game Progamming Patterns but I'm always getting Segmentation Fault.

Searching arround I saw that Segmentation fault happens when a program try to access a non allocated memory. So I tried hard to fix it, but I can't. Someone can help me?

Here is my code:

Observer.h

```
#ifndef OBSERVER_H
#define OBSERVER_H

#include "EntityAndEvent.h"
#include "Subjects.h"

class Observer
{
private:
    Observer* next_;
public:
    Observer()
    : next_(nullptr)
    {}

    virtual void onNotify(const Entity& entity, Event::Type event) = 0;


    // Other stuff...
    friend class Subjects;
};

#endif
```

Achievements.cpp

```
#ifndef ACHIEVEMENTS_CPP
#define ACHIEVEMENTS_CPP

#include "Observer.h"
#include <vector>

class Achievements : public Observer
{
public:
    enum Type{
        FELL_OFF,
        AWAKE_ON
    };
private:
    std::vector<Type> done{};
public:
    virtual void onNotify(const Entity&, Event::Type);
    void unlock(Achievements::Type);
    void printDone();
};

void Achievements::onNotify(const Entity& entity, const Event::Type event) 
{
    switch (event)
    {
    case Event::Type::ENTITY_FELL:
        if(entity.isHero())
            unlock(Achievements::Type::FELL_OFF);
        break;
    case Event::Type::ENTITY_AWAKE:
        if(entity.isHero())
            unlock(Achievements::Type::AWAKE_ON);
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
    }
};

void Achievements::unlock(Achievements::Type achiev) 
{
    done.push_back(achiev);
}

void Achievements::printDone() 
{
    // assert(done.size());
    for(size_t i{0}; i < done.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << done[i] << "\n";
    }
};
```

EntityAndEvent.cpp (i create this just to work with observer and subjects)

```
#ifndef ENTITY_AND_EVENT_H
#define ENTITY_AND_EVENT_H

class Entity
{
public:
    inline const bool isHero() const {return true;}
};

class Event
{
public:
    enum Type{
        ENTITY_FELL,
        ENTITY_AWAKE
    };

};

#endif
```

Subjects.h

```
#ifndef SUBJECT_H
#define SUBJECT_H

#include "Observer.h"

#include <vector>

class Observer;

class Subjects
{
private:
    // when implements this, prefer to use linked list or another optimized algorithms
    Observer* head_{};

protected:
    void notify(const Entity& Entity, Event::Type event);
    
public:
    Subjects() : head_(NULL)
    {};
    ~Subjects() {}

    void addObserver(Observer* observer);


    // const int getNumObs() const {return num_obs_;}
};
#endif
```

Subjects.cpp

```
#include "Subjects.h"
#include <cassert>

void Subjects::notify(const Entity& entity, Event::Type event) 
{
    Observer* observer = head_;
    while (observer != NULL)
    {
        observer->onNotify(entity, event);
        observer = observer->next_;
    };
};

void Subjects::addObserver(Observer* observer) 
{
    if (head_ != nullptr)
        observer->next_ = head_;
    head_ = observer;
};
```

Physics.cpp (i create this just to populates the subject)

```
#ifndef PHYSICS_H
#define PHYSICS_H

#include "Subjects.h"
#include "EntityAndEvent.h"

class Physics: public Subjects
{
private:
    
public:

    void update(const Entity& entity)
    {
        if (entity.isHero())
        {
            notify(entity, Event::Type::ENTITY_AWAKE);
        };
    };

};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Observer.h"
#include "Achievements.h"
#include "Achievements.cpp"
#include "EntityAndEvent.h"
#include "Physics.h"
#include "Subjects.h"
#include "Subjects.cpp"

int main()
{
    Physics *p{};
    Entity e{};
    Achievements *achiev{};
    p->addObserver(achiev);
    p->update(e);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It should be a **single** block of code, compilable as is. Not 7 files. And please don't #include .cpp files, it's a wrong way to manage your multi-file projects.

Answer (score 0):

With `Physics *p{};` you are declaring a pointer, but it currently does not point to a valid object (it is being initialized as `nullptr` here). Therefore, calling p->addObserver results in a segmentation fault. You should be able to confirm this by running the program in a debugger.

Why are you using a pointer here? Change `Physics *p{};` to `Physics p{};`.

---

Disclaimer: Since your code is definitely not a minimum example I didn't look into the whole code or even tried to compile it. I'm only posting an answer because there is a clear error in the `main` function (use of an invalid pointer) that results in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

first, tks for the reply. @darcamo that works. I dont know why it was declared as pointer.

I fixed that, so if anyone else have the same doubt check below:
main.cpp

```
#include "Observer.h"
#include "Achievements.h"
#include "EntityAndEvent.h"
#include "Physics.h"
#include "Subjects.h"

int main()
{
    Physics p{};
    Entity e{};
    Achievements achiev{};
    Observer* ptr_achiev{&achiev};
    p.addObserver(ptr_achiev);
    p.update(e);
        

    return 0;

}
```